# Excel 2010 work with multiple named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

My question is: Im working with named ranges in a large workbook. I need to copy data say from some named range in some worksheet x and paste it on another named range say wksheet y before i can sort it and display it on yet another range in wksheet z.

I have achieved all this through vba except for screen flickers alot when i execute the code.

Im using the statement **application.goto reference:=""** to select the ranges and this activates these sheets hence the flickering back n forth. which dosent look appealing.

Is there a way i could work with the sheets without activating them.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Read [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) please.

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to improve:

1. Start your code with:

   `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

   This will prevent the flickering. Make sure to reactivate it at the end with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. Else Excel will behave strangely, not updating the screen correctly after your macro is finished.
2. Instead of using

   ```
      Application.Goto Reference="YourRangeName1"
      Selection.Copy
      Application.Goto Reference="YourRangeName2"
      Selection.Paste
   ```

   use

   ```
   Range("YourRangeName1").Copy Target=Range("YourRangeName2")
   ```

   This will also speed up your execution time...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

use this code at the beginning of your vb project.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used Peter Albert's and it was fine